# Array trazendo resultados diferentes em PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

Tenho meu bd, porém, está me trazendo um resultado diferente do que está no banco

```
$consulta = "select * FROM PRODUTO_pedido WHERE PEDIDO_PED_ID =12";                        
$resultado = $db_con->query($consulta);
$contador = $resultado ->rowCount(); 
while ($row = $resultado-> fetch()){
  echo "<script>alert(".$row['PRODUTO_PROD_CODIGO'].")</script>";
}
```

Por exemplo, no bd o id está como `299007` e está me exibindo `01110105`.

Como resolvo?

Comment: Ja jogou essa sua query no banco mesmo para ver o retorno?

Comment: Faça um teste e troque a linha de `while ($row = $resultado-> fetch())` para `while ($noticia = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))`.

Answer (score 0):

Utilize o método `fetch_array` ao invés do `fetch`.
Seu código vai ficar assim:

```
$consulta = "select * FROM PRODUTO_pedido WHERE PEDIDO_PED_ID=12";                        
$resultado = $db_con->query($consulta);
$contador = $resultado ->rowCount(); 
while ($row = $resultado-> fetch_array()){
  echo "<script>alert(".$row['PRODUTO_PROD_CODIGO'].")</script>";
}
```

Usando `fetch_array`, você deixa explícito que quer tratar cada linha do resultado da `query` como um `array` separadamente dentro do laço de repetição.

Aqui tem a documentação:

https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Para utilizar o fetch, é necessário determinar uma associação (como visto na documentação: php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php):

```
stmt_bind_assoc($db_con, $row);
```